# How to get fixed/non-editable grouping in my table

Tags: material-react-table

I'm trying to figure out how to have fixed grouping in my table. If I set all columns to `enableGrouping` to `false` I can no longer manually add columns to the grouping. The next step is setting `grouping` to desired value in `initialState`. However, the grouping component at the top of the table is still visible and columns can be removed from grouping. Is there some way to disable the grouping component and have fixed grouping in my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be non-ideal as it has side effects, but setting `enableTopToolbar` to `false` serves my purpose. With this option, grouping component is no longer visible, but I also lose some of the options that were on the top toolbar. Alternatively I can set custom component in `renderTopToolbar` and add back some of those options (annoying but a possibility).